# Eclipse runs the previous program

Tags: c++, eclipse

I run this program and after that i get "Errors exists do you want to continue". Then i click yes and i get "Hello world" in the console. Which was the project i ran previously. 
Anybody knows what is the problem?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

int func() {
    return 42;
}

int main ( int argc, char ** argv ) {
    auto x = func();
    cout << x << endl;
    cout << typeid(x).name() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need Eclipse? Did you consider compiling on the command line (perhaps using `make`); or maybe under `emacs` (`M-x compile`)

Comment: Click on Save All and try again :)

Comment: Yes, Eclipse by default does not save your source file before building it, as @MindPeace alludes to, which could very well be the problem. There is an option in Eclipse to force saving open documents when you build. When Eclipse tells you there are problems building, it doesn't generate an executable (how can it? there are problems...), and after telling it to continue anyway, what would you expect?

Comment: i saved everything and still doesn't work? I am losing patience whit Eclipse. I think it is really not that good for c++. What do you think about Qtcreator?

Comment: emacs is too complex for me to set up.

Answer (score 0):

You may not have selected to run the right program. If you hover over the Run option in Eclipse, it'll give you a tool tip telling you what program it's going to run.

EDIT: Click the drop-down next to the run option, and see if your current program is in the list. If it isn't you need to make a run configuration for it. If don't have a run configuration, to make one, you click the drop down next to run > Run Configurations... > double click C/C++ Application > and fill in the proper information. After that click finish, and select that run configuration.

Comment: when i hover over run nothing happens.

Comment: @Seba Check the edit I made and see if that helps you.

Comment: My program is in the list.

Comment: @Seba Then open the drop down and click the program to run it.

Comment: I ran it and got the message:  
"Errors exist in a required project. Continue lunch?. "If I click yes I get "Hello world" in the console. Which is the program i ran before this one.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Project Explorer window, right click on your project and click on "Build Project".
Now click on the Run button at the top (The green play button at the top). 
If you have errors, maybe its actually looking for the last build that ran without error.
Let me know what happened when you tried this so I can assist you further.

Comment: After build i get the message "Errors exist in a required project. Continue lunch?. "